# Drawing bitmap fragments to the Display N18 Module in .Net MF 4.2

Tags: bitmap, .net-micro-framework

I'm trying to draw bitmaps to the [Display N18](https://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/425) from a STM32F405RGT6 (I think that's similar to the one on the [FEZ Cerberus](https://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/349)) running NetMF 4.2

When I try to follow [the instructions for drawing a bitmap fragment to the N18 display](https://www.ghielectronics.com/docs/59/display-n18-module) I'm not sure what bit depth to use. The instructions recommend using Paint, which saves bitmaps by default at 24 bit but later in the code the byte array size calculation `byte[] newRender = new byte[128 * 160 * 2];` makes me think it should be 16bit. What is the bit depth the N18 expects?

When I run the sample code I get an error.

```
var tdata = Resources.GetBytes(Resources.BinaryResources.yes_no);
var picture = new Bitmap(tdata, Bitmap.BitmapImageType.Bmp);
var newRender = new byte[13*79*2];
Array.Copy(newRender, picture.GetBitmap(), newRender.Length);
_display.DrawRaw(newRender, 13, 79, 50, 50);
```

The second line throws the error:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.SPOT.Graphics.dll`

Why do I get this error and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Over [on the GHI forum](https://www.ghielectronics.com/community/forum/topic?id=15362) I got an answer. I can use the code fragment in https://www.ghielectronics.com/community/codeshare/entry/744 to convert bitmaps into the required byte format. This saves space too. The usage code provided needs to be adapted with the following lines as `TinyBitmap` has been dropped from the GHI interface. [taylorza](https://www.ghielectronics.com/community/user/7512) provides the following fix to his sample:

```
var tdata = Resources.GetBytes(Resources.BinaryResources.yes_no);
_display.DrawRaw(tdata, 13, 79, 50, 50);
```